# Movie genre classification using machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning

could you review my below code to train a machine learning model to classify movie genres? I've used the data from [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/rounakbanik/the-movies-dataset?select=movies_metadata.csv)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import ast
import joblib
from collections import Counter

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import hamming_loss, accuracy_score, f1_score, classification_report
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
import xgboost as xgb


def preprocess_data():
    print('Preprocessing data...')
    df = pd.read_csv('../data/movies_metadata.csv', low_memory=False)
    df = df[['overview', 'genres']]
    df.dropna(inplace=True)
    
    # Clean up the genres column
    df['genres'] = df['genres'].apply(ast.literal_eval) \
                              .apply(lambda x: [i['name'] for i in x])
    
    # Filter out rare genres
    counter = Counter([genre for sublist in df['genres'] for genre in sublist])
    GENRE_FREQ_THRESHOLD = 10
    popular_genres = [genre for genre, count in counter.items() if count >= GENRE_FREQ_THRESHOLD]
    
    df['genres'] = df['genres'].apply(lambda genres: [genre for genre in genres if genre in popular_genres])
    
    # Drop rows with no popular genre
    df['genres'] = df['genres'].apply(lambda genres: genres if len(genres) > 0 else np.nan)
    df.dropna(subset=['genres'], inplace=True)
    
    # One hot encoding of genres
    mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
    df_genres = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df.pop('genres')),
                              columns=mlb.classes_,
                              index=df.index)
    
    joblib.dump(mlb, '../models/mlb.joblib')
    
    df = df.join(df_genres)
    df.to_csv('../data/processed_movies_metadata.csv', index=False)


def train_model(X_train, y_train, encoder, multilabeler, estimator):
    if encoder == 'TfIdf':
        encoder_model = TfidfVectorizer().fit(X_train)
    elif encoder == 'SentenceTransformer':
        encoder_model = SentenceTransformer('all-MiniLM-L6-v2')
        encoder_model.transform = encoder_model.encode
    
    X_encoded = encoder_model.transform(X_train)
    classifier = multilabeler(estimator=estimator)
    classifier.fit(X_encoded, y_train)
    return (encoder_model, classifier)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    preprocess_data()
    df = pd.read_csv('../data/processed_movies_metadata.csv')
    X = df['overview']
    y = df.drop(['overview'], axis=1)
    
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
    # Reset indices so that SentenceTransformer encode doesn't complain
    X_train.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    y_train.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    X_test.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    y_test.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    
    print('Training model...')
    encoder = 'SentenceTransformer'
    multilabeler = OneVsRestClassifier
    estimator = LogisticRegression()
    
    encoder_model, classifier_model = train_model(X_train, y_train,
                                           encoder, multilabeler, estimator)
    y_pred = classifier_model.predict(encoder_model.transform(X_test))
    report = classification_report(y_test, y_pred, output_dict=True)
    print("F1 Score: %.4f"%(report['micro avg']['f1-score']))
    print("Hamming Loss: %.4f"%(hamming_loss(y_test, y_pred)))
    
    joblib.dump(encoder_model, '../models/encoder_model.joblib')
    joblib.dump(classifier_model, '../models/classifier_model.joblib')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice variable names throughout, very standard.

---

> coding: utf-8

That has been the default encoding for a very long time,
so you might remove it.
I can't imagine there's anything in your toolchain
for which it makes a difference.

---

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    preprocess_data()
    df = pd.read_csv('../data/processed_movies_metadata.csv')
```

The `if __name__` guard is nice.
May as well push down all these statements
so they're within `def main():`,
and then we're guarding just a single line which calls main().
Why?
So local variables go out of scope upon exiting main().
And so it's easy to rename to something more meaningful
as you write and write more code and then you step
back to notice what it really does once you've finished it.

Now, let's work on that data directory.

```
from pathlib import Path

    data_dir = Path('../data').resolve()
    assert data_dir.exists()
```

You might also consider defining a `models_dir` parameter.

And let's modify the preprocess signature so
we're passing in a CSV filespec.

```
    preprocess_data(data_dir / 'movies_metadata.csv')
    df = pd.read_csv(data_dir / 'processed_movies_metadata.csv')
```

But, wait!
The last preprocessing step was to write that out.
[DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).
Rather than evaluating the preprocessor for side effects,
returning `None`, it makes more sense for it to
`return` that processed CSV pathname.
Better still, since it already has a dataframe
of joined genres, it should simply `return df`
and then caller won't need to re-read a CSV.

---

Ok, back to the program in progress.

```
    df = pd.read_csv(...)
    df = df[['overview', 'genres']]
```

That's a pretty typical approach that naturally falls out
of iterative hacking, nothing wrong with it.
We read many columns and project down to just two of them.
Consider telling pandas about that up front:

```
    df = pd.read_csv(... , usecols=['overview', 'genres'])
```

---

```
    df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Again, there's nothing super wrong with that.
But it would be
[better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60020384)
to get in the habit of phrasing it this way:

```
    df = df.dropna()
```

I have had too many colleagues run afoul
of the dreaded `SettingWithCopyWarning`,
and then it takes forever to explain why
a script that ran fine for months is
suddenly not behaving as expected after
one tiny edit.
Avoid `inplace` -- you don't need it.

Similarly when you later drop rows with no popular genre,
and when you reset indexes.

---

```
    df['genres'] = ... .literal_eval) \
                              .apply(lambda x: [i['name'] for i in x])
```

[Pep-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length)
encourages you to wrap the assigned expression within "extra"
`(` `)` parentheses, no biggie.

The lambda is nice enough, but conventionally we name that expression
[itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).

---

```
    X = df['overview']
```

This is fine.
It's worth noting that

```
    X = df[['overview']]
```

would have given you a DataFrame rather than a Series.
Possibly you would then have less "reset_index" trouble.

---

Don't be afraid to write a one-sentence """docstring"""
for each function you define.

---

This code achieves its design objectives.

I would be willing to delegate or accept maintenance
tasks for this codebase.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the answer. Sure, please feel free to checkout the github repo.
https://github.com/t-thirupathi/movies-genre